# Get directory name from array in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of paths from which I want to extract folder name

I wrote:

```
@echo off

set paths[0]="C:\p\test1" 
set paths[1]="C:\p\test2" 
set paths[2]="C:\p\test3"

(for %%p in (%paths%) do (
   for %%F in (%%p) do echo Processing %%~nxF
))
```

but seems that nothing is shown.

I expected to see:

> Processing test1
>
> Processing test2
>
> Processing test3

Comment: You may also want to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990). I think you need to enable delayed expansion.

Comment: Nice, post it as answer and I'll accept it ! It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes a big difference if first `"` is specified on a `set` command line left to variable name or left to variable value. In most cases it is better to specify it left to the variable name, especially if a variable value holding a path should be concatenated later with a file name to a full qualified file name.

See also: [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

The solution for this task is:

```
@echo off

set "paths[0]=C:\p\test1"
set "paths[1]=C:\p\test2"
set "paths[2]=C:\p\test3"

for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('set paths[ 2^>nul') do echo Processing %%~nxJ
```

The command **FOR** with option `/F` and a set enclosed in `'` results in starting one more command process running in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line specified between the two `'` appended as further arguments. So executed is in this case with Windows installed to `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c set paths[ 2>nul
```

The command **SET** outputs all environment variables of which name starts with `paths[` line by line using the format `VariableName=VariableValue` to handle **STDOUT** of started background command process.

It could be that there is no environment variable of which name starts with `paths[` which would result in an error message output to handle **STDERR** by command **SET** which would be redirected from background command process to handle **STDERR** of the command process which is processing the batch file and for that reason would be displayed in console window. For that reason a possible error message is redirected by the background command process to device **NUL** to suppress it with using `2>nul`.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `set` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures in this case everything written to handle **STDOUT** of started background command process and process this output line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

Empty lines are ignored by **FOR** which does not matter here as there are no empty lines to process.

**FOR** would split up a non-empty line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and would assign just first space/tab separated string to specified loop variable, if it does not start with default end of line character `;`. This default line splitting behavior is not wanted here. For that reason the option `delims==` defines the equal sign as string delimiter.

The option `tokens=1*` instructs **FOR** to assign in this case the variable name to specified loop variable `I` and assign everything after the equal sign(s) after variable name without any further string splitting on equal signs to next loop variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is in this case `J`. That is the reason why loop variables are interpreted case-sensitive while environment variables are handled case-insensitive by the Windows command processor.

In this case only the variable value is of interest in the body of the **FOR** loop. For that reason just loop variable `J` is used on **ECHO** command line while `I` is not used at all.

The modifier `%~nxJ` results in removing surrounding double quotes from string value assigned to loop variable `J` and next get the string after last backslash or beginning of string in case of the string value does not contain a backslash at all. This is the name of the last folder in folder path string.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`

---

**UPDATE:**

There is a big advantage of this solution in comparison to the other two solutions posted up to now here:

There is not used [delayed environment variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) which is always problematic on working with file or folder names on not being 100% sure that no folder and no file contains ever an exclamation mark in its name.

Let us compare the three solutions with unusual folder names containing `!`.

```
@echo off
rem Make sure there is no environment variable defined of which name starts with
rem paths[ as suggested by Compo which is a very valuable addition on my code.
for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set paths[ 2^>nul') do set "%%I="

set "paths[0]=C:\p\test1!"
set "paths[1]=C:\p\!test2"
set "paths[2]=C:\p\!test!3"

echo(
echo Results of solution 1:
echo(
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('set paths[ 2^>nul') do echo Processing %%~nxJ

echo(
echo Results of solution 2:
echo(
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (0,1,2) do (
    for %%j in (!paths[%%i]!) do echo Processing %%~nxj
)
endLocal

echo(
echo Results of solution 3:
echo(
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Call :process paths "!paths[0]!" "!paths[1]!" "!paths[2]!"
Endlocal
echo(
pause
exit /B

:process
Set P_C=0
Set /a P_C-=1

For %%a in (%*) DO (
    CALL :populate %1 "%%~a"
)

Set /a P_C-=1

For /L %%b in (0,1,!P_C!) DO (
    ECHO Processing %1[%%b] = "!%1[%%b]!"
)
GOTO :EOF

:populate
Set "%1[!P_C!]=%~2"
Set /a P_C+=1
GOTO :EOF
```

The output on running this batch file is:

```
Results of solution 1:

Processing test1!
Processing !test2
Processing !test!3

Results of solution 2:

Processing test1
Processing test2
Processing 3

Results of solution 3:

Processing paths[0] = "C:\p\test1\p\\p\3"
```

Solution 1 as posted here works for all three folder names correct.

Solution 2 omits for first and second folder name the exclamation mark which will most likely cause errors on further processing. The third folder name is modified to something completely different. Enabled delayed expansion results in parsing a second time `echo Processing %%~nxj` after `%~nxj` being replaced by `!test!3` with interpreting `test` in folder name now as environment variable name of which value is referenced delayed. There was no environment variable `test` defined on running this batch file and so `!test!3` became just `3` before `echo` was executed by Windows command processor.

Solution 3 produces garbage on any folder name contains an exclamation mark, even on full qualified folder name defined before enabling delayed expansion and referenced with delayed expansion on calling the subroutine `process`.

Well, folder and file names with an exclamation mark in name are fortunately rare which makes the usage of delayed expansion usually no problem. But I want to mention here nevertheless the potential problems which could occur on any folder name containing one or more `!`.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer as it is exactly the same methodology I would have used. I would however have added something additional, _(to replace the empty line 2)_, `For /F "Delims==" %%I In ('Set paths[ 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%I="`. This ensures that there are definitely no existing defined variable names beginning with `paths[` so that only those defined within the script are returned by the [tag:for-loop] on line 7.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that should work :

```dos
@echo off
set paths[0]="C:\p\test1" 
set paths[1]="C:\p\test2" 
set paths[2]="C:\p\test3"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (0,1,2) do (
    for %%j in (!paths[%%i]!) do echo Processing %%~nxj
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the Array within the function.
This approach can be used to define multiplay Arrays.

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: REM P_C is used to define the range of the Array. The -1 operations on P_C is to shift the paths parameter out of the Arrays working Index.

::REM the first parameter passed is used as the Arrays Name. all other parameters are assigned to index values 0 +

Call :process paths "C:\p\test1" "C:\p\test2" "C:\p\test3"

pause

:process
Set P_C=0
Set /a P_C-=1

For %%a in (%*) DO (
CALL :populate %1 "%%~a"
)

Set /a P_C-=1

For /L %%b in (0,1,!P_C!) DO (
    ECHO Processing %1[%%b] = "!%1[%%b]!"
)
GOTO :EOF

:populate
Set "%1[!P_C!]=%~2"
Set /a P_C+=1
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: For more information on Arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/59680701#59680701